# Regex: Match all words that contains some special characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in which 3 kind of words are repeating:

```
class="text"
style="line-height:13.5pt">
{font-family:
```

I want a regex to match these "words", which may contain characters like `"` `>` `:`  `=` `-` `{` `}` as well as the standard "word characters" that can be matched using`\w`.

I made a regex:

```
(\w)+(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w+[\{+\=+\"+\}+\:])\w+
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a character class that includes both traditional word chars and your extra ones:

```
[\w">:={}-]+
```

Note that you don't need to escape those chars inside a character class. This even includes the hyphen when it's first or last.

Comment: SUPER answer ! Thank you very much, Bohemiam. Seems that you understood my problem, without asking me any other things.

Comment: Thanks. I edited your question to try to make it clearer.